# Is the following conditional expectation correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

The following is very important in my research: suppose that $U_t, V_t$ are independent real stochastic processes defined with respect to the same filtration and probability space

Suppose that for $r,s >0$ I need to estimate $\mathbb{E}\left \{ \left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_r,V_r)]-h(U_r) \right)\left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_s,V_s)]-h(U_s) \right) \right\}$
for some regular functions $h,g$.

Suppose that for fixed $u$ the following inequality holds
$$\mathbb{E}[ g(u,V_r)]-h(u) \leq C e^{-r} $$
for some constant $C$ independent of $u$ and for every $r>0$.

Can I proceed in the following way?

Consider $(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)$ to be the sigma algebra generated by $U_\tau$ and compute for some deterministic continuous function $\overline U_\tau$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} & \left \{ \left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_r,V_r)]-h(U_r) \right)\left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_s,V_s)]-h(U_s) \right) \right\} \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left \{ \mathbb{E} \left \{ \left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_r,V_r)]-h(\overline U_r) \right)\left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_s,V_s)]-h(\overline U_s) \right) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)\right\} \right \}\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left \{ \mathbb{E} \left \{ \left( \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[g(\overline U_r,V_r) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)]]-h(\overline U_r) \right) \\
 \times \left( \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[g(\overline U_s,V_s) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)]]-h(\overline U_s) \right) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)\right\} \right \}\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left \{ \mathbb{E} \left \{ \left( \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[g(\overline U_r,V_r) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)]-h(\overline U_r)] \right) \\
 \times \left( \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[g(\overline U_s,V_s) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)]-h(\overline U_s)] \right) |(U_\tau= \overline U_\tau, \tau \leq r \vee s)\right\} \right \}
\end{align}
and now I want to apply the inequality (since u has been fixed by conditioning)
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} & \left \{ \left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_r,V_r)]-h(U_r) \right)\left( \mathbb{E}[g(U_s,V_s)]-h(U_s) \right) \right\} \\
& \leq C^2 e^{-r} e^{-s}
\end{align}

In particular is it correct to double condition like that to the same $\overline U$ in both the interior expectation and the external one so that I can use the inequality?

Comment: The third equality doesn't make sense. It would work if $\mathsf{E}g(u_1,V_r)-h(u_2)\le Ce^{-r}$ for any $u_1,u_2$.

Comment: Yes it is what I was afraid about.. How do you show formally that is wrong?

Comment: @d.k.o. How do you show formally that is wrong?

Comment: $U$ in the inner expectation is not affected by the conditioning in the outer expectation in the sense that
$$
\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[X]-X\mid X=x]\ne 0,
$$
unless $\mathsf{E}X=x$.